# Chrome is synchronously handling iframe loading, whereas Firefox handles it asynchronously

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, iframe

The following code in question causes differences to appear between Chrome and Firefox:

```html
<button id="add">add element</button>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
  const c = document.querySelector("#container");
  document.querySelector("#add").onclick = function() {
    const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    c.appendChild(iframe);

    const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    h1.innerText = "hello";

    iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(h1);
  };
</script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vtbcu1zj/

Try running the above code in Chrome (should work fine), and also in Firefox (breaks).

It seems that this is because Firefox doesn't assume that the iframe instantly loads, whereas Chrome does. The following change makes the code work in both browsers:

```js
iframe.onload = function () {
  iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(h1);
}

c.appendChild(iframe); // append after setting up event listener
```

What is the reason for this discrepancy? Is this a bug or a feature? Is Chrome making an incorrect assumption here or is Firefox handling this incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome is wrong, [per specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#process-the-iframe-attributes),

> [...] if the element has no src attribute specified, and the user agent is processing the iframe's attributes for the "first time"
>
> Queue a task to run the [iframe load event steps](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#iframe-load-event-steps).
>     The task source for this task is the DOM manipulation task source.

So they should actually wait that the current event loop finished before calling these *iframe load event steps* which are responsible to generating the iframe's document.

At the time you called `iframe.contentDocument` getter, it should have returned `null`.

But indeed, as an author, you should wait for the `onload` event, which should always fire asynchronously.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Seems a bit weird that Chrome _always_ (in my many use cases) seems to have it rendered and loaded on time. Do you have a source for this information regarding the parallelity of the iframe's load process? Thanks!

Comment: @Lucas-BetterCodingAcademy [it's here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#process-the-iframe-attributes), second bullet "Queue a task to run the iframe load event steps. ..."

Comment: Thanks for informing me on this! Perhaps you could garnish your answer to make it more informative to others who might face similar issues. :)

Comment: Yes, but actually reading it, I saw I got it wrong... I got confused with other resources loading like <img> which should be made in parallel, but here specs explicitely ask that in this case, it's a *queue a task* operation that should be made, i.e the generation of the document shoult not be made at least before the next "enter the event loop" operation (that is after our script execution ended).